# How to give permission to guard using Spatie

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

I am new to Laravel and I am having modify an existing Laravel application to only give some permission to a guard.

When I use the command `php artisan permission:show`, I see the following:

```
   Guard: admin
    +---------------------------------------+---------------+
    |                                       | Administrator |
    +---------------------------------------+---------------+
    | admin                                 |  ✔            |
    | admin.admin-user.create               |  ✔            |
    | admin.admin-user.delete               |  ✔            |
    | admin.admin-user.edit                 |  ✔            |
    +---------------------------------------+---------------+

Guard: commenter
+-------------------------------+-----------+
|                               | Commenter |
+-------------------------------+-----------+
| admin.comment-activity.create |  ·        |
| admin.comment-activity.delete |  ·        |
+-------------------------------+-----------+
```

As far as I understand in the above output, Commenter does not have the permission for `admin.comment-activity.create` and `admin.comment-activity.delete`. Is there a command I can use to provide this permission?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation:

`$user->givePermissionTo('edit articles');`

& to revoke it:

`$user->revokePermissionTo('edit articles');`

Source: https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/basic-usage/direct-permissions